# output dimension for language model

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp

I am working on language model. In the final layer I am using dense layer with output size equals to vocab size and this layers contribute huge parameters to train.

How can I reduce the size of the final layer in the language model? Does the final layer's size should be equal to vocab size, if yes then will the model not be large if we have large vocab?

Comment: Could you please add a bit of code to clarify the question? Else you might want to try another S/E site, such as Data Science.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the final layer's size should be equal to size of the vocabulary. Here is an example of the Decoder from the [TF tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/text/tutorials/nmt_with_attention#the_decoder):

```
# This fully connected layer produces the logits for each output token.
self.output_layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(self.vocab_size)
```

To fix the size of the model, you can set the maximum vocabulary size on the [Text Vectorization](https://www.tensorflow.org/text/tutorials/nmt_with_attention#text_vectorization) step.